# Dynamically load video in embedded player

Tags: javascript

I have a video player on my web page:

```
<object id='mediaPlayerobj' width="320" height="285" 
                        classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
                        codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
                        standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
                        <param id='movie' name='fileName' value="">
                        <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
                        <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
                        <param name='autoStart' value="true">
                        <param name='showControls' value="true">
                        <param name='loop' value="true">
                        <embed type='application/x-mplayer2' 
                            pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
                            id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
                            bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
                            showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="320" height="285"
                            src="" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true">
                        </embed>
                    </object>
```

I have left the filename value blank because I want to dynamically set it. I have a grid view and into that I load a list of videos that are stored on our server. I want the player to load up the movie from the server. Here's my JavaScript:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvPresentations.ClientID %>');
        var cell = grid.rows[(+index) + 1].cells[2].textContent;
        var path = "d:\\Presentations\\";
        document.getElementById('movie').value = path + cell;
```

However nothing happens when I change the filename element. What am I missing?

Comment: (By the way I'm rubbish at front end stuff. Prefer staying behind the scenes...)

Comment: are you sure to have `#` in  `gvPresentations.ClientID`?
if not change `getElementById('<%=` to `getElementById('#<%=`